# How to convert a double to two decimal places in netezza

Tags: netezza

I have tried everything I could on Netezza! Here is what I've tried:

1. `SELECT 45/CAST(7 AS DOUBLE)` ---> 6.4285714285714
2. But I want results to be 6.43 so I tried `SELECT ROUND(45/CAST(7 AS DOUBLE), 2)` but get an error: `'NZOLEDB' failed with no error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21)`.
3. Also tried `SELECT 45/CAST(7 AS DOUBLE) :: DECIMAL(5,2)`. Get same as error as in point 2 above.

Could someone please assist! It's very frustrating.

Comment: Are you querying database directly or indirectly from some kind or programming language?

Comment: I am querying directly from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select to_number((45*1.0)/7,99.99);
TO_NUMBER
-----------
 6.42
(1 row)


SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select version();
              VERSION
-----------------------------------
 Release 7.0.4 (P-1) [Build 33519]
(1 row)
```

Hope this will give you desired result.

Comment: Thanks Varun. But, I get this: "ERROR:  Numeric overflow.  Value does not fit in a numeric(2,2)". I wonder if it has something to do with the version of Netezza. This is how the system info looks like: Workbench: Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics 4.2.1671.22924 (2/24/2014)
OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
DBMS Version: Release 6.0.8 (P-1) [Build 25429]
Driver Used: Netezza OleDb
Driver Signature: NZOLEDB
ODBC Version: Unknown or not installed
NZOLEDB OleDb Version: 6.0.3.17780